# How to extract properly from single line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have text lines like this

```
"name                       carl (verified)"
```

How I can get something like:

```
["name", "carl", "verified"]
```

I am using:

```
text.scan(/\((.*?)\)/)
```

but it matches only inside `()`.

Comment: Rules generally cannot be inferred from a single example. For example, your example does not tell the reader what is to be matched in `"$name 1 [(verified)] \"cat\""`.You need to state your question, unambiguously, in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight-forward way here including a lot more slack on how much space is present:

```
m = text.match(/\A(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*\z/)
```

Then you can get the data out of `m` like `m[1]` and so forth.

The idea here is you need to have three separate captures on your string. `scan` is great for pulling out repeating patterns but far less useful for one-shot extractions.

Answer (score 2):

```
"name                       carl (verified)".scan(/\w+/)
# => ["name", "carl", "verified"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the character class:

```
text.scan(/[^\s()]+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"name                       carl (verified)".delete("()").split
  #=> ["name", "carl", "verified"]
```